# If/Then statement not working inside of while loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

The if/else statement inside of this loop will not work. If I enter "no" it still continues the loop. I don't understand why, any help would be appreciated.

```
while keepPlaying == True:
    play = input(str('Would you like to play rock, paper, scissors? Yes or no?\n'))

    if play == str('yes') or str('Yes'):
        playerChoice = input(str('Ok! what\'s your choice?\n'))
    else:
        keepPlaying = False

print ('Thanks for playing.')
```

I've put the code through a visualizer and even if the variable play != yes or Yes it still chooses the == to path.

Comment: Why do you keep converting strings to strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if play == str('yes') or str('Yes'):
```

It is equivalent to:

```
if (play == str('yes')) or str('Yes'):
```

Note that `str('Yes')` is always truthy (and with an `or` means you'll never get the `false` part).

You want:

```
if play in ('yes', 'Yes'):
```

Or maybe (just a tip):

```
if play.lower() == 'yes':
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition to `play in ('Yes', 'yes', 'y', 'Y')`

The issue is, the second part of the `or` clause (`str('Yes')`) **always evaluates to `true`**.